# How many times a file hit by multiple queries in Lucene (JAVA)

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on lucene using java code implementation. I have searched a phrase e.g. "Software Engineering, software development" using `ShingleFilter (TokenStream input, int minShingleSize, int maxShingleSize)` from Index directory. Its working well. Output is:

```
Phrase Searching:software engineering software
Found 5 hits.
1. Index Document ID:336 File Name: jucs_243.pdf.txt
2. Index Document ID:506 File Name: jucs_4.pdf.txt
3. Index Document ID:524 File Name: jucs_419.pdf.txt
4. Index Document ID:276 File Name: jucs_189.pdf.txt
5. Index Document ID:340 File Name: jucs_247.pdf.txt

Phrase Searching:software engineering software development
Found 1 hits.
1. Index Document ID:506 File Name: jucs_4.pdf.txt
Phrase Searching:engineering software development
Found 1 hits.
1. Index Document ID:506 File Name: jucs_4.pdf.txt
```

My question is: How many times a single file hits in Java? My code is:

```
// display search results

TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);

ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;

System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");

for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) { 
      int docId = hits[i].doc;  
     // print some info about where the hit was found...  
      Document d = searcher.doc(docId);  
      System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " +"Index Document ID:"+ docId + "File Name:" + d.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));  

}
```

Comment: required output  as:                                                                                                             1. Document ID:336 Hits:(1)                                                                            
2. Document ID:506 Hits:(3)
3. Document ID:524 Hits:(1)
4. Document ID:276 Hits:(1)
5. Document ID:340 Hits:(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed this task using

```
    static TreeMap<Integer, Integer> Total_Hits = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

My code is:

```
     for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i){ 
      int docId = hits[i].doc; 
      if(Total_Hits.keySet().isEmpty() == true)
          {
            Total_Hits.put(docId,1);
          }
      else 
         {
            if(Total_Hits.containsKey(docId))
                {Total_Hits.put(docId,Total_Hits.get(docId).intValue()+1);}
            else
                { Total_Hits.put(docId,1);}

         }
```

Output:

```
Document ID:276  No oF Hits : 1  Time
Document ID:336  No oF Hits : 1  Time
Document ID:340  No oF Hits : 1  Time
Document ID:506  No oF Hits : 3  Time
Document ID:524  No oF Hits : 1  Time
```